# Trouble to interpret and decide witch variation of fixed effect model to use - variables in levels or differences

Tags: regression, econometrics, fixed-effects-model

I am having trouble in deciding which regression to use in a project. I want to test whether changes in tariffs ($\tau_{st}$) on sector $s$  are related somehow to changes in employment levels $y_{ist}$ considering a panel of firms $i$, on sectors $s$, year $t$.

My panel is short, in that $t = 1, 2$. My panel is unbalanced - there are firms present on only one period, as well as in both.

I know that when with 2 time periods, taking first differences is equivalent to using fixed effects.

However, I am unsure about what to run given what I intend to analyze - should I run regressions with $y$ and $\tau$ in levels or in first differences? The latter option really confuses me since I don't have observations for every period.

Having said that, what would be the implication of interacting $\tau_{st}$ with a time indicator $D_t$?  I feel tempted to do that since in more traditional DiD models with a binary treatment effect, standard practice is regressing the outcome variable on a treatment dummy, a time dummy $D_t$ and an interaction of both.

What is the difference between these models:
$$ y_{ist} = \beta \tau_{st} + \lambda_t + \mu_i + \epsilon_{ist}$$
$$ y_{ist} = \beta D_t \cdot \tau_{st} + \mu_i + \epsilon_{ist}$$

$\lambda_t$ and $\mu_i$ are time and firm fixed effects, respectively.

Is there a problem in using my variables on levels?

Comment: It would help if you were to describe just how unbalanced your data is wrt firms having one vs two time periods. Obviously, firms with only one period will be removed when differencing. Moreover, firms without two time periods will add nothing to the interpretation of the model, as described by Morgan Kelly in his recent paper *Understanding Persistence* https://www.researchgate.net/publication/344044108_Understanding_Persistence

Comment: About half of the observations are in both periods. The other half if roughly equally split between firms seen only in t =1 or only in t=2.

Comment: Besides, what do you mean by adding nothing to the interpretation? The model would have the same coefficients as the estimation considering only the balanced observations?

Comment: The OP is interested in *change* between two periods. Having firms with only one period of information doesn't reflect that. In fact, those observations are misleading information.